# javascript functions arguments

Tags: javascript, html

Have created a basic form, three drop down lists and a button. im tryn to multiply the three values in the down lists. i have to pass the data up to the function. i have ran the code just keep getting 0 as the result?? I don't think I'm passing the data from from up to the function correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function multiply(number1, number2, number3)
{
    var firstnum=0;
    var secondnum=0;
    var thirdnum=0;
    var answer;
    firstnum=parseInt(number1);
    secondnum=parseInt(number2);
    thirdnum==parseInt(number3);
    answer=(firstnum*secondnum*thirdnum);
    alert(answer)
}

</script>

<form name="Example1">
Number 1:
<select id="num1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br/>
Number 2:
<select id="num2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br/>
Number 2:
<select id="num3">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type=button value="muliply" onclick="multiply(num1.value, num2.value, num3.value)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to check the syntax is proper always...@Francis Gall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is:

`thirdnum==parseInt(number3);` is a *comparison*, not an assignment, so `thirdnum` will always be `0`.

Since you are multiplying by `thirdnum`, and anything × 0 is 0, you will always get 0 as the output.

Change `==` to `=`.

This would have been picked up if you had QAed your code with [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/).

---

Your bad practises which you should fix are:

1. `num1.value` assumes global JS variables will be created for every element with an id. Don't assume that, use `document.getElementById`
2. `parseInt(number1)` doesn't have a radix. Always specify the number system you are using (normally base 10) so it isn't inferred from the data for unexpected results: `parseInt(number1, 10);`
3. `<form name="Example1">`, the name attribute on forms is a legacy from before the `id` attribute had come around properly. Use `id` to identify elements for client side code.
4. `onclick` attributes do a poor job of [separating concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (or a library such as YUI or jQuery if you need to support old versions of IE).

Answer (score 0):

OK u keep getting 0 as result because of this

```
thirdnum==parseInt(number3);
```

in your `multiply` function

Change it to

```
thirdnum=parseInt(number3);
```

And you should be good to go

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gL8n/)